# How many edge-disjoint copies of $s$-complete graph $K_s$ in the complete $s$-partite graph $K_{l,l,\dots,l}$ with each part of size $l$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many edge-disjoint copies of $s$-complete graph $K_s$ in the complete $s$-partite graph $K_{l,l,\dots,l}$ with each part of size $l$?

For vertex-disjoint case, the answer is simple, just $l$ copies of $K_s$. But it seems there are much more edge-disjoint copies of $K_s$ in $K_{l,l,\dots,l}$. How many could it be? Is there any known result about it?

Comment: Well obviously every copy of $K_s$ must have exactly one vertex in each part of $K_{l..l}$. Further two copies are edge-disjoint iff they share at most one vertex. So what you are looking for is a maximal set of s-tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_s), 1 \leq x_i \leq l$ such that no two tuples agree in two or more places.

Comment: Any known result about this maximal set? Or it is too obvious...

Comment: Doesn't seem obvious to me, greedy selection does not succeed in general. For $s=2$ the answer is $l^2$ and for large $s$ it is $l$.

Answer (score 1):

We’ll follow wonce’s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428701/how-many-edge-disjoint-copies-of-s-complete-graph-k-s-in-the-complete-s-pa#comment5016636_2428701) and denote the maximum size of a required family of $s$-tuples by $t(l,s)$.

Clearly, if $s=1$ then we can take all $l$ $s$-tuples, so $t(l, 1)=l$. Farther we’ll assume that $l\ge 2$.

Since there are at most $l^2$ distinct possibilities for the pair $(x_1,x_2)$, $t(l,s)\le l^2$.

For a prime number $p$ we can show $t(p,p)\ge p^2$ by finding required $p^2$ $p$-tuples $t^{ij}$ in the product $\Bbb Z_p^p$  of the groups $\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ of residues modulo $p$. For any $(i,j)\in \Bbb Z_p^2$ and $1\le k\le p$ put $t^{ij}_k\equiv i+j(k-1)\pmod p$. Assume that two tuples $t^{ij}$ and $t^{i’j’}$ have common $k_1$-th and $k_2$ elements. Then 
$i+j(k_1-1) \equiv i’+j’(k_1-1) \pmod p$ and $i+j(k_2-1)\equiv i’+j’(k_2-1) \pmod p$. Subtracting one of the equalities from the other, we obtain $(j-j’)(k_2-k_1)\equiv 0\pmod p$. Since $l$ is prime and $k_1\not\equiv k_2\pmod p$, we have $j\equiv j’\pmod p$, which implies $i\equiv i’\pmod p$.

[Due to lower approximation of naturals by primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447334/asymptotics-of-the-lower-approximation-of-a-pair-of-natural-numbers-by-a-coprime),
the above construction suggests that if $r=\min\{s,t\}$ then $t(l,s)\ge r^2-O(r\sqrt{r})$.

Now we consider small $l$.

We have $t(2,3)=4$ as shows the family $\{(1,1,1), (1,2,2), (2,1,2), (2,2,1)\}$ of triples. I can show that $t(2,4)=2$, and then by induction I can prove that $t(l, (l^2+l)/2+1)=l$.