# Calculate unique combinations for unique guests per table contraint

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I'm working on this application that generates a table layout based on some criteria. The criteria consists of these things

- A list of guests
- The amount of tables
- The amount of dinner courses
- The type of algorithm

  1. Place guests at table at random
  2. Place guests at a unqiue table each course
  3. Place guests at a table with other unmet/unique guests each course

Right now I'm looking for the formula to calculate the constraint for the last algorithm (nr 3).
After spending some time googling I found a formula for combinations/permutations, though it only works when the maximum amount of guest per table is less then three.

$$
\frac{n!}{r!(n − r)!}
$$

In my cause I use r as the amount of guests and n as the amount of guest per table
( e.g. ceil( guest count / table count ) )

For example,
With 4 guests and 3 tables, n=4 and r=2, the formula returns 6. Which matches my calculations

```
12 23 34
13 24
14
```

Same for 6 guests and 3 tables, n=6 and r=2, the formula returns 15. This also matches the calculations

```
12 23 34 45 56
13 24 35 46
14 25 36
15 26
16
```

But when the guests per table increases, the formula returns unwanted results. For example, n=7 and r=3, returns 35. But my calculation comes down to 7 combinations

```
123 246 356
145 257 347
167
```

I was hoping if someone could help me find or alter this formula so it matches these three calculations. Thus honoring the constraint:
**maximum amount of combinations where each number can only be returned once in combination with the other numbers.**

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n\ge r\ge 2$. Denote by $f(n,r)$ the maximum amount of combinations of $r$ numbers from $n$ numbers where each number can only be returned once in combination with the other numbers.

Given a required system of $f(n,r)$ combinations, let $N$ be a total number of pairs  of numbers participated in some of these combinations. Each of combinations of the system has ${r\choose 2}$ pairs, and all pairs are mutually distinct, so $N={r\choose 2} f(n,r)$. On the other hand, there can be at most ${n\choose 2}$ pairs in total, so $f(n,r)\le \frac {n(n-1)}{r(r-1)}.$

Ot the other hand, if there exists a [Steiner  system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) $S(2,r,n) $ then 
it yields an exact answer with $f(n,r)=\frac {n(n-1)}{r(r-1)}$. In particular, we have it [when $n$ has a form $6k+1$ or $6k+3$ for some $k$ and $r=3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Steiner_triple_systems), 
or [$n=q^2$ and $r=q$ or $n=q^2+q+1$ and $r=q+1$, where $q$ is a power of a prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system#Examples) ([we still cannot construct respective Steiner systems for other $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373801/for-which-q-there-exists-a-steiner-system-s2-q-q2)). Also see pictures for  $n=7$ and $r=3$  and  $n=13$ and $r=4$ [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PACbj.gif). Finally I remark that the above examples [provide an asymptotic lower bound for $f(r^2,r)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447334/asymptotics-of-the-lower-approximation-of-a-pair-of-natural-numbers-by-a-coprime).