# Golomb Rulers and Sets with Unique Sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

A set of integers ${\displaystyle A=\{a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{m}\}}$ where ${\displaystyle a_{1}<a_{2}<...<a_{m}}$ is a Golomb ruler if and only if
$$ 
\text{for all }
i,j,k,l \in \{1,2,...,m\}
{\text{ such that }}
i\neq j
{\text{ and }}
k\neq l, a_{i}-a_{j}=a_{k}-a_{l}\iff i=k{\text{ and }}j=l.
$$

A [modular Goloumb ruler](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/cs507/Projects/2003/JustinColannino/#Modular%20Golomb%20Rulers) works the same, not on a line but on a circle of length $q$.
I wonder how these rulers are connected to sets $B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_m\}$, where $b_1<b_2<...<b_m$ and the sum $b^\star=\sum_{k=1}^m b_k \bmod q$
is unique, in the sense, that every other sum of $m$ elements of $B$ (e.g. $b^{\text{other}_1}=2b_1+b_3+...b_m \bmod q$), has a value other than $b^\star$. So I don't bother if $b^{\text{other}_k}=b^{\text{other}_l}$, only $b^\star$ shall be unique.

Can Goloumb Ruler help to generate the sets $B$ as well?

They were for example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6936438/1179936), to a question that looks similar to my question...

Comment: The sets from the linked answer are related to Golomb rulers, but they differ from sets with unique sums. The sequences to sum consist of $m$ elements for the latter, but of consecutive elements for the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each set $B$ with unique sums $\mod q$ is a Golomb ruler $\mod q$. Indeed, if there exists $i,j,k,l \in \{1,2,...,m\}$
such that $i\neq j$ and $k\neq l$ and ($i\ne k$) or $j\ne l$) but $b_{i}-b_{j}=b_{k}-b_{l} \pmod q $ then $b^*=b^*+b_i+b_l-b_j-b_k \pmod q$, a contradiction.

The condition for $B$ to be a set with unique sums  ($\mod q$) is much stronger than to be a (modular) Golomb ruler and the former sets are much sparse than the latter.

Indeed, if $B=\{b_1,\dots, b_m\}$ is a set with unique sums $\mod q$ and $m’=\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ then all ${m\choose m’}$ sums of subsets of $B$ of size $m’$ are distinct, which follows ${m\choose m’}\le q$.  By [Robbins’ bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) for each $m\ge 2$ we have $$\frac {2^{m-1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi (m+\delta)}}\exp\left(-\frac {1}{4(m+\delta)-1}\right)<{m\choose m’}<\frac {2^{m-1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi (m+\delta)}}\exp\left(-\frac {1}{4(m+\delta)+1}\right),$$
where $\delta$ equals $0$, if $m$ is even and $1$, is $m$ is odd.

On the other hand, the constructions at the page you linked suggest that at least for some $q$ there exist modular Golomb rulers of size close to $\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: +1, thanks, are you saying that, when I ask, for $\b^\star$ being unique, among all other sums with the same number of terms (dupes allowed), I get a exponentially large set of unique sums of $B$ for free? Concerning the other hand: Would you suggest to just scan Singer/Bose/Ruzka constructions for my additional condition?

Comment: @draks... Yes for the first question. For the other hand, I don’t see how modular Golomb rules can help to construct a set with unique sums $\mod q$. Or what additional condition do you mean?
PS. The upper bound above for a size of  a set with unique sums $\mod q$ is rather tight, because  if $m\ge 2$ and $(m-2)2^{m-1}+1<q$ then a set $\{2^0,2^1,\dots, 2^{m-1}\}$ has unique sums $\mod q$.

Comment: Ok, but what then do mean by "the page you linked suggests that at least for some $q$ there exist modular Golomb rulers of size close to $\sqrt{q}$."?

Comment: @draks... I guess the lenght of the modular Golomb rulers for the constructions mentioned there is about $q$. I tried to check this looking at “James B. Shearer's Golomb Ruler page with a piece on modular Golomb Rulers” linked there, but the page doesn’t exist.

Comment: Hi, I found a cached version of the linked page at https://web.archive.org/web/20171225101048/http://www.research.ibm.com/people/s/shearer/grule.html but it is not very helpful in my opinion...

Comment: @draks... OK. But each Golomb ruler of length $L$ is also a Golomb ruler $\mod q$ for each $q>2L$. Therefore for each natural $n$ and each $q>2G(n)$, where [$G(n)$ is a shortest lenght of a Golomb ruler with $m$ marks](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/cs507/Projects/2003/JustinColannino/#Optimal%20Golomb%20Rulers%20and%20G(n)). In particular, [Erdős–Turán construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler#Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_construction) shows that $G(p)\le 2p^2-2p+1$ for each odd prime $p$.

Comment: The respective bounds can be adapted for non-prime $n$ using the approximations from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447334/asymptotics-of-the-lower-approximation-of-a-pair-of-natural-numbers-by-a-coprime) my question.

Comment: @draks... I fixed a constant in the approximation of ${m\choose m’}$. Sorry for the error.